# Find average of cells in a column based on other cells in their respective rows Google Spreadsheets

Tags: function, google-sheets, conditional-statements

this is my first time on this site.

Using Google Spreadsheets, how do I take the average of cells in a column, but ONLY count them in the average IF the cell in another column of their respective row has a value of 1. Is that possible?

For example: In the fake columns below, I would want to take the average of the values in B when the corresponding value in column A is equal to 1. If A is equal to 0, I don't want it to count in the average for column B.

A   B

1   1 (count in the average)

1   0 (count in the average)

1   1 (count in the average)

0   1 (don't count in the average)

1   1 (count in the average)

0   0 (don't count in the average)

0   1 (don't count in the average)

Answer (score 2):

```
=AVERAGEIF(A1:A7,1,B1:B7)
```

[Syntax](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256529)

Answer (score 1):

Create a third column that is A*B. Then calculate the average by dividing the sum of the third column by the sum of column A.

Answer (score 1):

Also possible with AVERAGE/FILTER:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(B1:B7,A1:A7))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved with QUERY:

```
=query(A:B,"select avg(B) where A=1. label avg(B) ''")
```

Answer (score 0):

Also possible with sum/count:

```
=sumif(A:A,1,B:B)/countif(A:A,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with an array formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(A:A*B:B)/sum(A:A))
```